# Please guide a proper script to have the dynamic results by using dynamodb and nodejs

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

By writing this below code i am writing the script again and again to have the added records, without writing the script again and again i want added records in resulting. Using dynamodb and nodejs. Please provide the correct script.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var async = require("async");

AWS.config.update({
      region: "us-west-2",
      endpoint: "2345",
      accessKeyId: "A",
      secretAccessKey:"x"
    });

var db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

var table = "rets_property_all";
var pstart =new Date () .getTime ();

async.parallel({
        0 : function(callback){
        db.scan ({TableName: table,
        ProjectionExpression: "#cityname,ListingKey ",
        FilterExpression: "#cityname = :v_id",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#cityname": "CityName",
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {":v_id" : 'BALTIMORE'},
            TotalSegments: 2,
            Segment:  0//by the worker who has been called
        },function (err , res) {
            callback (null , res.Items);
        });
            },
            1 : function(callback){
        db.scan ({TableName: table,
          ProjectionExpression: "#cityname,ListingKey ",
          FilterExpression: "#cityname = :v_id",
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              "#cityname": "CityName",
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {":v_id" : 'BALTIMORE'},
            TotalSegments: 2,
            Segment: 1//by the worker who has been called
        }, function(err,results){
      if (err) {throw err; }
      var pend = new Date () .getTime ();

      console.log (results);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code using `async.parallel`.

The number of segments needed to get all 3000 items in one go depends on the size of the items. You may need to calculate the size of the whole data to determine the number of segments. You can keep the maximum number for segments. If the data is not found for the particular segment scan, DynamoDB doesn't throw an error.

```
var scanFunctions = [];
var totalSegments = 11;
var segmentNos = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

segmentNos.forEach(function (segmentNo)  {
    console.log(segmentNo);
    var scanFunction = function (callback) {
        console.log("scanning ..." + segmentNo);
        db.scan({
            TableName: tableName,
ProjectionExpression: "#cityname,ListingKey ",
    FilterExpression: "#cityname = :v_id",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#cityname": "CityName",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {":v_id" : 'BALTIMORE'},
            Segment: segmentNo,
            TotalSegments: totalSegments                  
        }, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error ===>" + JSON.stringify(err));
            } else {
                console.log("SegmentNo ===>" + segmentNo + "   ;Data ===>" + JSON.stringify(res));
            }
            callback(err, res.Items);

        });

    }
    console.log('pushing scan funs to array....');
    scanFunctions.push(scanFunction);
});

async.parallel(scanFunctions, function (err, results) {
    console.log("Results ===>" + JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, for you for useful response and I want to know how many segments I have to take for my entire records for example 3000 records. Please provide your guidance.

Comment: I want the above code using parallel asynchronous. Please provide as soon as possible. I want the result in one scan which is scan limit greater than 1mb. I want the code in that sense, Please guide me. That means my total 3000 records scanned in one time only.

Comment: I am having 3000 records, I want to display all the 3000 records in a single scan using parallel asynchronous of dynamodb. Please guide me. Above code is for foreach but I want to use with parallel asynchronous. Please provide me the code.

Comment: Thank u inadvance

Comment: I want to scan all the total segments in one scan only.

Comment: I am paused in the middle of my project, so please help me.

Comment: If you want one scan, you dont need to use segments... you can use scan without segments. Your requirement is unclear ...

Comment: Please provide the code for single scan ... Waiting for your reply.